# Binary search for name

Tags: python, search, binary-search

I have a list of countries in a separate file (countries.txt), and I need to do a binary search to find a country, and for it to state the information given on it.

My file:

```
Afghanistan,    647500.0,   25500100

Albania,    28748.0,    2821977

Algeria,    2381740.0,  38700000

American Samoa, 199.0,  55519

Andorra,    468.0,  76246

Angola, 1246700.0,  20609294
```

If I wanted to find the area and population for Albania, and I put `getCountry(Albania)` in the shell, how would I get it to state the provided info?

I have this so far...

```
def getCountry(key):

    start = "%s" #index
    end = len("%s")-1 #index
    while start<=end:
        mid = (start + end) / 2
        if '%s'[mid] == key: #found it!
            return True
        elif "%s"[mid] > key:
            end = mid -1
        else:
            start = mid + 1
    #end < start 
    return False
```

Comment: This can be done in `O(1)` time if you store the data in a dictionary, and use the country name as key.

Comment: Im new to this. How do i store the file in the dictionary and then use it

Comment: I suspect its for an assignment that requires binary search ...

Comment: well yes its for an assignment, but I am asking a question because i dont understand how to put a binary search for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary:

```
def get_countries(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        country_iter = (line.strip().split(',') for line in f)
        return {
            country: {"area": area, "population": population}
            for country, area, population in country_iter
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = get_countries("countries.csv")
    print(d)
```

If you really have your heart set on a binary search, it looks more like this:

```
def get_countries(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]

def get_country_by_name(countries, name):
    lo, hi = 0, len(countries) - 1
    while lo <= hi:
        mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
        country = countries[mid]
        test_name = country[0]
        if name > test_name:
            lo = mid + 1
        elif name < test_name:
            hi = mid - 1
        else:
            return country
    return countries[lo] if countries[lo][0] == name else None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = get_countries("countries.csv")
    print(a)
    c = get_country_by_name(a, "Albania")
    print(c)
```

But this is coding a binary search off the top of my head. If you don't have to code the binary search and can use a library routine instead, it looks like this:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def get_country_by_name(countries, name):
    country_names = [country[0] for country in countries]
    i = bisect_left(country_names, name)
    return countries[i]
```

Comment: Thanks for the binary search, can you explain everything about your if statement at the end?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = get_countries("countries.csv")
    print(a)
    c = get_country_by_name(a, "Albania")
    print(c)

Comment: It's a test driver for the code. It calls the code and shows how it works. Documantation here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html

Comment: okay and for def getcountry(countries, name): what would i put for the 'countries' variable? Sorry im truly a beginner

Comment: `get_country_by_name` takes two arguments: (1) a list of countries and (2) the name of a country. Each `country` is a list made up of (1) country name, (2) area of the country, and (3) population of the country. And that is exactly what should be loaded from file by `get_countries`.

Comment: this might sound stupid but how would i input "a list of countries" for the first argument?

Comment: I've given you three solutions (a dictionary, a binary search from the ground up, and a binary search using library routines). I've given you code to load the data from a file and to put it into the data structures. I've given you a test driver to demonstrate usage for each solution. I've explained how to call this code. I think that is enough to get you started. We are pretty deep into doing your homework at this point. Find a tutorial on python and follow it through. Then come back to your question and you will understand it all.

Answer (score 1):

Conquer this problem in steps.

1. Start with a sorted list, and implement a binary search on the list in a function.
2. Make sure it works for empty lists, lists of one item, etc.
3. Write a function to take an unsorted list, sort it and return the result on it from the first function.
4. Write a function that takes a list of tuples with a string as a key and other strings as data. It should sort the data on your key, and return what you want.
5. Write a function that reads a file and constructs data compatible with 4 and returns the selected item.

Pat yourself on the back for solving your more complex problem in digestible steps.

Note: This clearly is an assignment to learn how to implement an algorithm. If it were truly to find the information from a file, using a dictionary would simply be wrong. Correct would be to read each line until the country was found making a single comparison for on average one half of the entries in the file. No wasted storage, no wasted time comparing, or hashing.

Answer (score 0):

As Ashwini suggested in his comment, you can use the dictionary in python. It will look something like this:

```
countries = {'Afghanistan': (647500.0, 25500100),

    'Albania': (28748.0, 2821977),

    'Algeria': (2381740.0, 38700000),

    'American Samoa': (199.0, 55519),

    'Andorra': (468.0, 76246),

    'Angola': (1246700.0, 20609294)}

print countries['Angola'][0]
```

You can learn more about `dictionary` and `tuple` from [this python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: I would +1 this in a heartbeat if you built the dict from the txt file :P

Answer (score 0):

the other answer is correct you **should** use a dictionary but since Im guessing this is an assignment the first thing you need is a list

```
with open("countries.txt") as f:
     #filter(none,a_list) will remove all falsey values (empty strings/lists/etc)
     #map(some_function,a_list) will apply a function to all elements in a list and return the results as a new list
     #in this case the iterable we are handing in as a_list is an open file handle and we are spliting each line on ","
     country_list = filter(None,map(lambda x:x.split(","),f))
```

then you just need to search through your ordered list like any other binary search

in order to do a binary search you do something like (recursive version)

```
def bin_search(a_sorted_list,target):
    mid_pt = len(a_sorted_list) // 2
    if target < a_sorted_list[mid_pt]:
        return bin_search(a_sorted_list[:mid_pt], target)
    elif target > a_sorted_list[mid_pt]:
        return bin_search(a_sorted_list[mid_pt:], target)
    elif target == a_sorted_list[mid_pt]:
        return mid_pt
```

in your case you will need some minor modification

Comment: I have this script:

def getCountry(key):
 
with open("countries.txt") as f:
  
country_list = filter(None,map(lambda x:x.split(","),f))

  
start = "%s" #index
  
end = len("%s")-1 #index
  
while start<=end:
   mid = (start + end) / 2
   if '%s'[mid] == key: #found it!
    return True
   elif "%s"[mid] > key:
    end = mid -1
   else:
    start = mid + 1
  #end < start 
  return False

how do i put the 'countries.txt' in a dictionary

Comment: for a_sorted_list, would i put my "countries.txt"?

Comment: nope you would probably use `county_list` ... but it still needs some minor work to work for your data

Comment: okay im just a little confused on how this would look on the script including the 
with open("countries.txt") as f: 
country_list = filter(None,map(lambda x:x.split(","),f))

Comment: If the OP didn't know what a how to put the data into a dict, I'm sure they aren't familiar with what `filter` and `lambda` are (or do).  Perhaps some explanation would be helpful?

Comment: what part is confusing you have a sorted list and a function to call ... which of those do you not know how to do? how are you doing a class where you have to do a binary search without knowing how to call a function?

Comment: I do not really know how to put everything in you explained to me. Im in an intro to computer science course. and half the class is washouts from last year so its moving really fast.  This is all new and so im sorry for being very slow to learn this. but im a visual learner

Comment: Your binary search is wrong. You need to reverse these two lines: `return bin_search(a_sorted_list[mid_pt:], target)` and `return bin_search(a_sorted_list[:mid_pt], target)`. You are recursing on the lower half if the target is really in the upper half, and recursing on the upper half if the target is in the lower half.