# python binary search and file i/o

Tags: python, sorting, search, file-io, binary-search

This is for part of an assignement on which I am stuck...
I am new to python and I want to create a program which searches through a file which looks like this only longer:

```
Afghanistan,    647500.0,   25500100
Albania,    28748.0,    2821977
Algeria,    2381740.0,  38700000
American Samoa, 199.0,  55519
```

As you can see, the spacing is not always even... I want to convert the text part to a string, the area (second column) to a float and the third column (population) to an integer but have no idea how to approach it.
Here is what I have so far:

```
def readcountries():
    with open("countries.txt") as file:
        lines = [line.split() for line in file]
```

Which returns a 2 dimensional list (this is required)...But I cant figure out how I will convert the area and population to their appropriate types. I must then run a binary search on the country names > any hints? I know how to do this on numbers but on names?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question yesterday as user3207521? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714485/binary-search-for-name/21714939

Comment: nope not me...but maybe someone in my class haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a list comprehension here; it can be done but becomes ugly fast:

```
def readcountries():
    with open("countries.txt") as fh:
        rows = []
        for line in fh:
            name, area, population = line.split(',')
            rows.append([name.strip(), float(area), int(population)])
```

The list comprehension version would be:

```
def readcountries():
    with open("countries.txt") as fh:
        rows = [[n.strip(), float(a), int(p)] 
                for line in fh for n, a, p in (line.split(','),)]
```

Using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) would save you some processing:

```
import csv

def readcountries():
    with open("countries.txt") as fh:
        reader = csv.reader(fh, skipinitialspace=True)
        rows = [[n, float(a), int(p)] for n, a, p in reader]
```

Here the module handles the splitting and stripping, producing list objects for each line.

For a binary search, Python lets you compare strings with `<` and `>` just fine; strings are compared lexicographically. `ab` is smaller than `ac`, but `ba` is greater than `ab`. In other words, a string that would be sorted before another are considered 'smaller'.

As such, binary search on a sorted list of strings is no different from a binary search on a sorted list of numbers. Do make sure you only look at the first element of the tuples:

```
def bisect_right(rows, country, lo=0, hi=None):
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(rows)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if country < rows[mid][0]:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid + 1
    return lo

def bisect_left(rows, country, lo=0, hi=None):
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(rows)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if rows[mid][0] < country:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            hi = mid
    return lo
```

Comment: `line.split()` should be `line.split(',')`

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: `[[n, float(a), int(p)] for line in file for n, a, p in (line.split(','),)]`

Comment: okh that the reason you shifted strip() in append. Thanks for the trick

Comment: Your indexes are a bit unconventional: http://pastebin.com/etPVDYWU I would expect them to start at 0.

Comment: @hughdbrown: it's a `bisect_right`; find the point to insert a new value.

Comment: @hughdbrown: added a `bisect_left` for you too.

Comment: Might be worth calling that out. If I asked for a binary search, I would expect to see an 'algorithm [that] finds the position of a specified input value (the search "key") within an array sorted by key value', not an algorithm that finds an insertion point for a new value -- not that bisect_\* are not valuable in many contexts.

Comment: @hughdbrown: the default `bisect.bisect` function is a 'insert here' function too. The point was to demonstrate that the OP should access `rows[mid][0]`, not `rows[mid]`, really.

Comment: First of, thanks to all for the great variety of answers. @Martijn, when you use rows[mid][0] how does that work? For example I have a some code for my binary search...it always returns False so I am definetely doing something wrong

Comment: `rows[mid]` is one of the lists with (country, area, population) data; `rows[mid][0]` is just the country value of that list.

Comment: Thank you, so knowing this I have done the binary search successfully (i couldnt use bisect though i don't really understand it yet haha) BUT how now I am trying to sort this list accordingly to the population hence [mid][2] by bubble sort...how can I proceed?

Comment: @sbhb91: that's too broad a question to answer in comments. Perhaps make that a new post?

Answer (score 0):

Split using a comma as the separator rather than the default which is whitespace. [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) takes an argument for this purpose. Each line will be split into a three-element list. You'll need to convert the second and third entries from strings to numbers using the [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) or [`float`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) functions.

Edit: This part of the Python tutorial has some [information about lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class Country that contains the members name,population and area

```
class Country:
    def __init__(self,name,area,population):
        self.name = name
        self.area = area
        self.population = population
```

try this code to read file and parse it and then sort array of country objects:

```
def readcountries():
    countries_array = []
    with open("countries.txt") as file:
        lines = [line.split(',') for line in file]
    for line in lines:
        country = line[0].strip(' ')
        area = line[1].strip(' ')
        population = line[2].strip(' ')
        countries_array.append(Country(country, area, population))

    sorted_countries = sorted(countries_array,key=operator.attrgetter('name'))
    print [country.name for country in sorted_countries]
```

Comment: Or: `country, area, population = (item.strip(' ') for item in line)`.